# Distribution of $\sqrt{npq}(X-np)$ for large n where $X$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$ and $q=1-p$

Tags: binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

**Question:** Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n,p$. Let $q=1-p$. What is the limiting distribution of $a(X+b)$ for large $n$, where $a=\sqrt{npq}$ and $b=-np$?

**My attempt:**
The moment generating function of $a(X+b)$ is

$\mathcal{M}_{a(X+b)}(t)=(pe^{a(1-p)t}+(1-p)e^{-apt})^n$.

The power series expansion of the bracketed term is $1 + \dfrac{1}{2} t^2 (a^2 pq) + \dfrac{1}{6} a^3 p (2 p^2 - 3 p + 1) t^3 +... = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} n(pq)^2t^2+...$

Here, I get stuck, as I was hoping for the expansion to be $1+\dfrac{t^2}{2n}$ which would give the limiting distribution as $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $a=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{npq}}$ because the "normalizing" formula is

$$Y=\dfrac{X-m}{\sigma}$$

with mean $m=np$ and standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{npq}$ for a Bin(n,p) distribution.

Comment: Thank you Jean Marie, so would you say that it is in fact a typo in the question? Does the distribution in my question actually converge to anything?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is typo ;  if you correct your computations, you will find that $Y$ has a N(0,1) distribution.